# Oracle SQL - How to "pivot" one row to many

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle 12c, I have a view, which takes a little time to run.  When I add the where clause, it will return exactly one row of interest.  The row has columns/value like this...

[image]

I need this flipped so that I can see one row per EACH "set".  I need the SQL to return something like
[image]

I know I can do a UNION ALL for each of the entry sets, but as the view takes a little while to run, plus there are about 30 different sets (I only showed 3 - Car, Boat, and truck)

[image]

Is there a better way of doing this?  I have looked at PIVOT/UNPIVOT, but I didn't see how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for UNPIVOT

```
WITH TEMP_DATA (ID1, CarPrice, CarTax, BoatPrice, BoatTax, TruckPrice, TruckTax)
AS (
select 'AAA', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 from dual )

  select TYPE, PRICE, TAX 
  from temp_data
  unpivot
  (
    (PRICE, TAX) 
    for TYPE IN 
    (
      (CarPrice, CarTax) as 'CAR',
      (BoatPrice, BoatTax) as 'BOAT',
      (TruckPrice, TruckTax) as 'TRUCK'
    )
  )
;
```

OUTPUT:

```
TYPE       PRICE        TAX
----- ---------- ----------
CAR            1          2 
BOAT           3          4 
TRUCK          5          6
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks.

Comment: @user1009073 no problem...fyi, noticed I had an unnecessary subquery in there which I just updated above.  Will still get the same results.